# Переименование названия картинки на id-пользователя

Tags: php

Я создал форму отправку фото на сервер, и мне нужно, чтобы фото принимало id пользователя с БД и переименовывало ее под его id. Ниже приложу код формы и кода php отвечающего за обработку этой формы.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="POST">
    <!-- Поле MAX_FILE_SIZE должно быть указано до поля загрузки файла -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3145728" />
    <!-- Название элемента input определяет имя в массиве $_FILES -->
    <input name="userfile" type="file" multiple accept="image/*,image/jpeg,image/png" />
    <input type="submit" value="Загрузить" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
 require_once "/connect.php";
 $avatar = getAvatar (1);
 $uploaddir = 'img/';
 $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

 echo '<pre>';
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Файл корректен и был успешно загружен.\n";
 } else {
    echo "Возможная атака с помощью файловой загрузки!\n";
 }
 print "</pre>";
 $renameAvatar = "";
 $rename = "img/'.$avatar['id'].'.png";
 rename($uploadfile, $rename);
?>
```

Comment: А можете подробно описать в каком этапе у вас ошибка? и какая ?

Comment: Ошибка в том, что файл не меняет имя на id при rename

Answer (score -1):

Если не ошибаюсь то с помощью функции rename вы можете переместить файл
rename($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)

Comment: Зачем переименовывать то, чему можно сразу задать верное имя?

Comment: вместо move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile) и  rename($uploadfile, $rename); использовать rename($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile). Результат будет тот же